# No dataGridView shown when added dynamically to TabPage

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabpage

I have a problem - when I try to add my dataGridView to a new `TabPage` I created dynamically, the dataGridView is only shown on 1 `TabPage`, not on all pages, as you can see in [the screenshot](http://shrani.si/f/2O/13B/2A8e6K5d/untitled.png). How can I fix this?

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        withoutChildren(treeView1.TopNode);
        int index = 0;
        foreach (TreeNode tn in ta)
        {

            TabPage tp = new TabPage();

            tp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            tp.Name = tn.Name.ToString();
            tp.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            tp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(579, 164);
            tp.TabIndex =index;
            tp.Text = tn.Name.ToString();
            tp.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

            tp.Controls.Add(dataGridView2);

            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);

            index++;

        }

    }
```

Comment: can you try to iterate througt them in code after that and open one by one?

Comment: A control can only have one parent.  Sounds like the grid shouldn't be in a TabControl.

Comment: You either create more DGVs or move the one you have to the selected  page on selecting another pages. Having the same DGV on many pages makes not much sense, does it? What is the purpose? You can have many DGV share the same DataSource, or better the same BindingSource.

Comment: You could do this:     `private void tabControl1_Selecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)    {         dataGridView2.Parent =  e.TabPage;     }`